# How to match values in one column and parse the matching value from different columns in R

Tags: r

I am really stuck on this problem to work in R. I need to grepl(`allgood` in column `C`), and if it is present, I want to parse the values in column `A` and column `B` from the row matching the preceding `allbad` in column `C` and get the result.

```
A          B            C
apple      ball         allbad-cat
                        allgood-car
dog        bark         allbad-pet
                        bull
                        dull 
                        allgood-pet
```

result

```
   A          B            C
apple      ball         allbad-cat
apple      ball         allgood-car
dog        bark         allbad-pet
                        bull
                        dull
dog        bark         allgood-pet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# find the index of column "C" starts with "allgood"
good.idx <- which(grepl("^allgood", df$C))
# find the index of column "C" starts with "allbad"
bad.idx <- which(grepl("^allbad", df$C))

# for each "good" index, find the maximum "bad" index smaller than the "good" index
good.bad.near <- sapply(good.idx, function(x){
    return(max(bad.idx[bad.idx<x]))
})

df$A[good.idx] <- df$A[good.bad.near]
df$B[good.idx] <- df$B[good.bad.near]
```

Works for your data.

If you have more columns to substitute, you can use the `for` loop.

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  df[, i][good.idx] <- df[, i][good.bad.near]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain what you did here. I am confused with the function part.

Comment: Additionally, say if we not only have A and B columns to be pasted, but have 100's of columns to be pasted, how can be paste those in the last two steps you have shown? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
library(zoo)
i1 <- !grepl('^(allbad|allgood)', df1$C)
df1[1:2] <-  lapply(df1[1:2], function(x) ifelse(i1, '', 
                           na.locf(replace(x, x=='', NA))))
df1
#      A    B     C
#1 apple ball apple
#2 apple ball apple
#3   dog bark   dog
#4                 
#5                 
#6   dog bark   dog
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[A=='', c('A', 'B') := NA][, 
           lapply(.SD, na.locf)][i1, c('A', 'B') := ''][]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("apple", "", "dog", "", "", ""), 
B = c("ball", 
"", "bark", "", "", ""), C = c("allbad-cat", "allgood-car", 
"allbad-pet", 
"bull", "dull", "allgood-pet")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```